# Using basis to prove statements about linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if it is correct to use basis if proving statements about linear maps. For example:

Prove that if $T^\ast = T$ then there is $S$ with $S^3 = T$.

I can prove it like this: By the complex spectral theorem there is a basis in which $T$ is diagonal: $D$. Then this matrix has cube root $S =D^{1/3}$. Therefore there exists $S$ with $S^3=T$.

In many other proofs I also use an argument with the basis in which $T$ is diagonal. Is this a good way to prove statements? Or is there an argument more abstract that does not use existence of matrix of linear operators and existence of basis with diagonal matrix? Or is this the correct argument?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct (not that $S$ is not unique, however). In cases where you study analytical functions of matrices, it's quite natural to study the spectrum of matrices, hence passing to a basis where a matrix is diagonal appears a logical step.